# Postfix: 554 5.7.1 Relay Access Denied

Tags: dns, postfix, smtp, dovecot

My Problem is this: I can send E-Mails from my E-Mail (evolutio@lars-dev.de) to my other Emails like @gmail @web @gmx ...

But when I try to send a E-Mail from GMail to evolutio@lars-dev.de I have the Error:

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:
     evolutio@lars-dev.de

Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain lars-dev.de by mx1.cw4.me. [195.138.240.200].

The error that the other server returned was:
554 5.7.1 <evolutio@lars-dev.de>: Relay access denied
```

My main.cf

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
.tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = lars-dev.de
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydomain = lars-dev.de
myorigin = $mydomain
mydestination = $mydomain, localhost.$mydomain,  localhost.localdomain, localhost
#mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, $mydomain
relayhost = smtp.lars-dev.de
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all

# Virtual mailbox settings
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:$config_directory/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
#virtual_mailbox_base = /var/spool/mail
virtual_mailbox_maps =
    proxy:mysql:$config_directory/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf,
    proxy:mysql:$config_directory/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_mailbox_maps.cf,
    proxy:mysql:$config_directory/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_catchall_maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps =
    proxy:mysql:$config_directory/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf,
    proxy:mysql:$config_directory/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit = proxy:mysql:$config_directory/mysql_virtual_mailbox_limit_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit_override = yes
virtual_maildir_limit_message = Sorry, the user's maildir has overdrawn his diskspace quota, please try again later.
virtual_overquota_bounce = yes
virtual_minimum_uid = 150
virtual_uid_maps = static:150
virtual_gid_maps = static:8
virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1

# SASL Authentication
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_exceptions_networks = $mynetworks
#smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = lars-dev.de
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth

# No open relay!
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = reject_invalid_hostname
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
#    permit
```

master.cf

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master").
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       -       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
# When relaying mail as backup MX, disable fallback_relay to avoid MX loops
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
        -o smtp_fallback_relay=
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}

dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRhu
  user=vmail:mail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}

#dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRhu
#  user=vmail:mail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}
```

Answer (score 2):

Email sent first to `MX` DNS records,.`A` records are used as fallback when `MX` records are missing.
Your DNS domain provides both `MX` and `A` records.

MTA at A record gives `lars-dev.de` as its name in SMTP greeting.
MTAs at two MX record give `www.contentways.de` as their name in SMTP greeting.

**Diagnose:**
It seems that due to DNS configuration email to your domain is not sent to your MTA/postfix.

**Suggested fixes:**
Make your domain MX record(s) point to the same host as A record OR remove MX records OR reconfigure MTA/postfix at host(s) provided by current MX records.

Comment: How I can solve the problem?

Comment: Make your domain `MX` record(s) point to the same host as `A` record **OR** remove `MX` records **OR** reconfigure MTA/postfix at host(s) provided by current `MX` records.